# How to order by localized String with hibernate search (@ElementCollection Map)

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, hibernate-search

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(length = 16, updatable = false)
  private UUID id;


  @Column(nullable = false)
  @KeywordField
  private String classifier;


  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = ATTRIBUTE_LOCALIZEDNAME)
  @IndexingDependency(reindexOnUpdate = ReindexOnUpdate.SHALLOW)
  @IndexedEmbedded(name = ATTRIBUTE_LOCALIZEDNAME)
  private LocalizedString localizedname = new LocalizedString();

}
```

and:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "localizedstring")
public class LocalizedString {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(length = 16, updatable = false)
  private UUID id;

  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "locale")
  @CollectionTable(name = "localizedstring_stringvalue", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "localizedstring"))
  @KeywordField(
    sortable = Sortable.YES,
    normalizer = BaseAnalysisConfigurer.NORMALIZER_SORT
  )
  private final Map<String, String> stringvalue = new HashMap<>();


}
```

These 2 entities reusult in 3 tables with the following data as example:

item table:

```
id;classifier;name;localizedname
item-id-1;SALUT;Herr;localized-sting-id-1
item-id-2;SALUT;Frau;localized-sting-id-2
```

localizedstring table:

```
id
localized-sting-id-1
localized-sting-id-2
```

localizedstring-stringvalue table:

```
localizedstring;locale;stringvalue
localized-sting-id-1;de;Herr
localized-sting-id-2;de;Frau
localized-sting-id-1;en;Mr
localized-sting-id-2;en;Mrs
```

now I can search and sort the item data by classifier like so:

```
Search.session(entityManager)
  .search(Organization.class)
    .where(
      queryBuilder.bool()
        .must(queryBuilder.match()
          .field("classifier").matching("something")
    )
    .sort(
      queryBuilder
        .field("classifier")
          .order(SortOrder.ASC)
    )
```

But I would like to sort the items by the value of the localized string, either in german or in english depending on the logged in user...
something like:

```
    Search.session(entityManager)
      .search(Organization.class)
        .where(
          queryBuilder.bool()
            .must(queryBuilder.match()
              .field("classifier").matching("SALUT")
        )
        .sort(
          queryBuilder
            .field("localizedname.stringvalue")
              .where("localizedname.locale" == "de")
                .order(SortOrder.ASC)
        )
```

is something like this possible somehow ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [possible](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-sort-common-filter), but it really won't perform well.

Instead, consider indexing data the way you actually need it at query time.

For example, use a [custom bridge](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-bridge-propertybridge) with [field templates](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-bridge-index-field-dsl-dynamic) to create one field per locale:

```java
  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "locale")
  @CollectionTable(name = "localizedstring_stringvalue", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "localizedstring"))
  @PropertyBinding(binder = @PropertyBinderRef(type = LocalizedStringsBinder.class))
  private final Map<String, String> stringvalue = new HashMap<>();
```

```java
public class LocalizedStringsBinder implements PropertyBinder {

    @Override
    public void bind(PropertyBindingContext context) { 
        context.dependencies().useRootOnly();

        IndexSchemaObjectField rootField = context.indexSchemaElement() 
                .objectField( context.bridgedElement().name() );

        rootField
                .objectFieldTemplate( "locale" )
                .matchingPathGlob( "locale_*" );
        rootField
                .fieldTemplate( "locale_value", f -> f
                        .asString() )
                .matchingPathGlob( "locale_*.value" );
        rootField
                .fieldTemplate( "locale_value_sort", f -> f
                        .asString().sortable(Sortable.YES)
                        .normalizer(BaseAnalysisConfigurer.NORMALIZER_SORT) )
                .matchingPathGlob( "locale_*.value_sort" );

        context.bridge( Map.class, new Bridge( rootField.toReference() ) );
    }


    private static class Bridge implements PropertyBridge<Map> {

        private final IndexObjectFieldReference rootFieldReference;

        private Bridge(IndexObjectFieldReference rootFieldReference) {
            this.rootFieldReference = rootFieldReference;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(DocumentElement target, Map bridgedElement, PropertyBridgeWriteContext context) {
            Map<String, String> strings = (Map<String, String>) bridgedElement;

            DocumentElement rootObject = target.addObject( rootFieldReference ); 

            for ( Map.Entry<String, String> entry : strings.entrySet() ) {
                String locale = entry.getKey();
                DocumentElement localeObject = rootObject.addObject( "locale_" + locale ); 
                String fieldValue = entry.getValue();
                localeObject.addValue( "value", fieldValue ); 
                localeObject.addValue( "value_sort", fieldValue ); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can search like this:

```
    Search.session(entityManager).search(Organization.class)
        .where( f -> f.bool()
            .must(queryBuilder.match()
              .field("classifier").matching("SALUT")
        )
        .sort( f -> f.field("stringvalue.locale_de.value_sort").asc() )
        .fetchHits( 20 );
```

Comment: the code you posted was not exactly working, but I was able to set it up correctly.
I think the issue was this line: ```DocumentElement localeObject = rootObject.addObject( "locale_" + locale ); ```, because "locale_*" is only defined as a template and templates can only be added as values not as objects.

also for the creation of the templates the documentation that you have linked says: "It’s better to always host your dynamic fields on a dedicated object field, to avoid conflicts with other templates."

Comment: @aminator Yes, I believe the problem was that I declared the field templates on `context.indexSchemaElement()` whereas I should have declared them on `rootField`. I fixed that, it should be better now? Otherwise, feel free to provide your own code, to help others :)